# Function by clicking and keyboard input

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I would like to execute a Javascript function in a dialog by clicking and pressing Enter. The first one works. Unfortunately, I can't implement the function ("addTask()" of the Save-Button) properly.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_new_task_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-new-item" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add new item</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <ul class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="errors.length > 0">
                        <li ng-repeat="error in errors">
                            {{ error }}
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                        <input ng-model="task.quantity" type="text" id="quantity" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="item">Item</label>
                        <input ng-model="task.item" type="text" id="item" class="form-control autocomplete"/>
                    </div>                   

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTask()">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
        $('.modal-new-item').keypress(function(e){
          if(e.which == 13) {
            addTask();
          }
        })
      })
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Directive:

```
    app.directive('commonKeyEnter', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                commonKeyEnter: '&'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('keyup keypress', function(event) {
                    if (event.which === 13) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            scope.$eval(attrs.commonKeyEnter);
                        });

                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
   });
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-new-item" common-key-enter="addTask()" role="document">
```

I don't make sure "keyup" and "keypress" work on div, you can try with all input elements in form:

```
    <input ng-model="task.item" common-key-enter="addTask()" type="text" id="item" class="form-control autocomplete"/>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your efforts! Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work yet.
i copied the app.directive code into my app.js under the app variable instantiation and common-key-enter="addTask()" into the modal-dialog div and the form-group input statement.

do i still need my javascript code? Do I have to pay attention to anything else?

Comment: Hi @br0ken.pipe, any errors in your console? Try to console.log something in directive, may be because modal render after directive ran.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="item">Items</label>
    <input ng-model="task.item" type="text" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && addTask()" id="item" class="form-control autocomplete"/>
</div>
```